# Use AHK to detect the "Vim Mode" for GUI windows and configure conditional mappings of keys

Tags: vim, ocr, autohotkey

### The motivating story (TL;DR)

Terminals, due to historical reasons, won't distinguish <kbd>tab</kbd> from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. This makes quite a mess when I use Vim: my muscle memory tells me that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> shall advance me forward to the next position in the "Jumplist", but some Vim-plugins do remap the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to do other good stuffs.

### Better defined task

Can I make a "conditional mapping" for active windows from `ahk_process gvim.exe` when no "special characters" are shown at the bottom left corner of the active Window? 
[image]

- For the window on the left, the Vim session is in "**Normal-mode**"
- For the window on the right, the Vim session is in "Insert-mode".
- Other modes do exist, like Visual-mode
  [image]

At the end of the days, I would like to map the <kbd>tab</kbd> key only in "**Normal-mode**". The best that I can come up with is to OCR a fixed region of pixels at the buttom-left corner, and make it a conditional. Yet, I am inexperienced for getting OCR jobs done in AHK.

Sidenote: I am asking for help from the Vim community the flipside of the same question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/may-i-have-a-vim-session-report-its-mode-in-its-window-title

Answer (score 2):

No need for OCR/AHK hacks.

`:nmap` (and `:nnoremap`) maps only in normal mode.

`:imap` (and `:inoremap`) maps only in insert mode.

etc.

See `:help :map-commands` for the variety of different mapping commands for variety of modes.

If a plugin is overwriting a normal-mode mapping for <kbd>Tab</kbd>, see who the offender is by using `:verbose nmap <Tab>` (or its equivalent, `:verbose nmap <C-I>`), then look at its documentation to see how to rebind it (or in the worst case, eliminate the culprit).

Comment: I am aware of the `:nmap` and `:imap`, yet, for `<tab>` and `<c-i>` they should share something fundamental in common, making it impossible to map them to different things. Thanks for the `:verbose` command! Recent source: https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/607

Comment: No, Ctrl-I and Tab are literally the same thing. But your post talks about mapping them to different things according to the _mode_ - which you can already do, without OCR.

Comment: Aha, I see. I should have been clearer in the post. Here is what I am aiming for when posting the question: to eventually implement *different* functionalities to `<tab>` and `<c-i>` in Normal-mode.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to grab Vim's current mode to make it available to another application; that would be really cumbersome. If your eventual goal is to send different keys for `<Tab>` / `<C-i>` to Vim (e.g. `<F13>` instead of `<Tab>`), and you only want Vim to react differently in certain modes (e.g. normal mode), you can just map the other modes to again unify both keys:

```
:nnoremap <F13> ... " Functionality A
:nnoremap <C-i> ... " Functionality B
:map! <F13> <C-i>   " Both keys continue to do the same in insert and command-line mode.
```

Comment: A bit of challenge is that I would like to keep the default functionality of `<c-i>` in normal mode, while mapping `<tab>` to be `:VimwikiNextLink` in normal mode. I tried `map! <F14> <c-i>; nnoremap <tab> <Plug>VimwikiNextLink; map! <c-i> <F14>`, but nothing happens. `<tab>` and `<c-i>` in normal mode got me nothing.

Comment: Update: restarting Vim shows a different observation ==>  `<c-i>` shall follow the new mappnig for `<tab>`, not its "preserved" original functionality.

Comment: You're mapping `<F14>` to `<C-i>` and vice versa (in insert mode, via `:map!`). Don't do that. Also, to map to a `<Plug>`-mapping, you have to use `:nmap`, not `:nnoremap`.

Comment: I see. Apparently, I am completely lost when trying to use `:map!`. I wanted to use `<tab>` to jump to the next "hyperlinke", and use `<c-i>` as normal. I bet it is also impossible to let Vim map `<c-i>` and `<tab>` to different things, in Normal Mode?

Comment: I think `<c-i>` is "mapped" as _jump_ to newer location in jump list, in normal mode? I would like to leave `<tab>` mapped to the special key (`<F13>`) only when Vim is in Normal mode. I would like to use `<c-i>` and `<c-o>` navigate the jump list.

Comment: please advise how I shall improve this posting. I am happy to rewrite the question to make things clearer. Given Vim's ability to "auto-update" its `titlestring`, no OCR is needed.

Comment: You've devised quite a complex setup to get different keys in Vim. If you still have trouble to correctly implement it, I honestly just would not do this, and instead use another key. Unless you're always working just on one machine (the one with this special setup), you don't gain anything from this trick.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the hassle: it indeed get complicated and I will be writing a long post [here](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/607), where everything started :)